# .Net api for generating entity framework models from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-first, edmgen

Does the entity framework provides an API for .net (c#) to generate models from an existing database? I don't want to use `EdmGen.exe`, because a direct integration would be nice.

Maybe even the code which is used by the `EdmGen.exe` provides some information, because they also have to use some API functionality.

This is needed, because i want to compile the models dynamicaly with roslyn at runtime, which is currently working pretty well with some demo models.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use the Database first approach? more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Because i compile the models with Roslyn dynamically and make it available in ironPython for customizing :)

Comment: Then give more info about your problem in the question, please.

Comment: The source code for edmgen2 is here, it will give you some insights on how to generate a edm from your own code: https://github.com/cincuranet/EdmGen2

Comment: In addition to EricEJ answer you can have a look also at this project
EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838  
but I think it does not use EF API (it generate the code directly starting from SQL Server but I'm not sure about it because usually I use edmgen).

Comment: Ok, if used `edmgen2` for generating some models. But why does i get an `ObjectContext` and no `DbContext`. Further more i get `ObjectSet` instead of the very nice `DbSet`. Event the Models aren't POCO. Thank you, maybe some one could explain why :)